# How does iOS AppStore handle multiple version targeting different version of iOS?

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

Let's say I have an app with two versions that target different versions of iOS:

- Version 1.0: Deployment target iOS 5
- Version 2.0: Deployment target iOS 8

My understanding is that when a user goes to the AppStore to download the app, this is the version they will get:

- iOS 5: Version 1.0
- iOS 6: Version 1.0
- iOS 7: Version 1.0
- iOS 8: Version 2.0

First, is this true?  Is it true that both versions will be offered in the AppStore?  And users will be given the opportunity to download the best version for their version of iOS?

Second, if someone is already running Version 1.0 and has an iOS version less than iOS 8, then they will not get notified about a new version and will not be able to download the new version (unless they upgrade to iOS 8)?

Answer (score 3):

I think when you upload an application, App Store save the version of the app, for example - Version 1.0 for iOS 7. And when you update the app to 2.0( for example ), and this version is for iOS 8, the user that use iOS 7 ( like iPhone 4 ) it will get a message like this[image: I tried this for Find My iPhone.]

Answer (score 3):

Developers can choose which previously uploaded app versions are still available for users.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In 2015, Apple introduced App Thinning:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html
- https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-404/